# Why is the function recognition of VSCode and WebStorm different?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, webstorm

I recently switched from VSCode to WebStorm. I changed the code color to my own color.

Different color recognition for features in VSCode and WebStorm. This causes problems when using WebStorm.

I made the function blue and the variable pink.
In vscode it is recognized as a function, but in webstorm it is recognized as a variable.

I think putting a function in a variable should be a function. Is there a way to make it blue when a function is assigned to a variable like in VSCode?

**WebStorm**

[image]

**VSCode**

[image]

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking. Are you saying you don’t like the colors of WebStorm with regards to what you’ve set a variable to?

Comment: exactly

I made the variables pink and the functions blue
In vscode, aaa is represented as a function, but
In webstorm, aaa is expressed as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what you mean, but both of the IDEs say that that function in any case returns void.